# Subversion - Checkout a parent directory

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

In my repository, lets say I have this:

```
Animal
  Dog
     Beagle
     Hound
     ...
```

Lets say I checked out Dog to a working directory and I realized, whoops, I really wanted to checkout Animal.

I can delete my working copy, the Dog directory, and checkout Animal, but is there way I can do so without deleting and checking out again?

If my working copy of Dog has Animal as a parent folder and I checkout Animal without deleting Dog, I get something like "subversion failed to add directory versioned same name already exists".

I'm also using tortoise.  Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem with deleting & checking out again? If you've already made changes, commit them, then start over.

Comment: It's not a problem.  That's what I did and it worked.  Just wondering if I there was a better way, or there is a more correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible directly.

The easiest way is to delete your working copy and do a new checkout of `Animal`.

If you have any changes in `Dog` that you'd like to keep, move `Dog` to a temporary location, checkout `Animal` and then copy `Dog` back into the `Animal` directory.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for **[`svn switch`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html)**, which updates your working copy to reflect a new path. Modified files don't get touched, though. In TortoiseSVN, right click and select "Switch..." from the context menu.

The more common use case for `svn switch` is to switch between branches that are rooted from the same point, so that you can have different views of the same code. But you can switch between arbitrary paths in your repository.

Comment: But my parent directory, Animal, isn't under version control, so I can't switch to it, at least not from Tortoise.  Maybe via command line?

Comment: I'm confused. How can your repository have Animal in it if it's not under version control? Is that a typo?

Comment: I did a copy (branch) to create Animal.  In my working copy, Animal doesn't have the .svn directory.  It's a folder that has the same name as the repository folder.  So my working directory is an exact duplicate of the repository structure, but I checked out Dog to Dog.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I found to avoid downloading from the svn server what already is on my disk, then updating or checkout is done using `--depth empty`. So something like: `svn co --depth empty Animal ; cd Animal ; svn update --depth empty Dog`

Anyway, the idea is to get `Dog` as a directory in to `Animal/.svn/entries`.

This "`--depth empty`" keeps svn from downloading the actual content, but svn does make the sub-directory (in this case, `Dog`) and svn does put an entry for the `Dog` sub-directory in `Animal/.svn/entries`.

Then replace the Dog sub-directory with the copy you already have.

You can check that this works by whacking one of the files somewhere in `Dog` and doing an `svn update` in the `Animal` directory. The whacked file should be pulled down from the svn server.

Comment: Doesn't work: then you get `Updating '.':
Skipped 'trunk' -- An obstructing working copy was found
At revision 13370.
Summary of conflicts:
  Skipped paths: 1` when doing `svn up` in `Animal`.

Comment: Been a long time, so I'm not sure what the problem is. SVN should be making the Animal and Dog directories, shouldn't it? So there should be no obstructing working copy.

Another idea is maybe SVN has changed since '13 so this trick doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can map parent directory.
To do that, you just need to delete `.svn` directory from "Dog" (child) directory and do `SVN Update` on Parent directory. It will make existing file as `Versioned` copy and will download delta content of `Dog` directory from SVN server.
Please Note: You should have exact directory structure as SVN directory structure.